# Access DTO and Struct using string variable in Go

Tags: go, struct, key, dto

I am trying to set some timestamps based off values in a struct and the dto in Go. I think I may need to use reflection here, but I am a beginner in Go and not quite sure how to attack this. Here's a glimpse of my existing code. I have approximately 300 configs I'd like to timestamp so I am trying to optimize my code by creating a function that will take the dto and the config and then process a timestamp if applicable. Specifically, I am having trouble on figuring out how to pass dto to the processTimestamp function below, and I am also not sure how to reference the string literal as a key name for both the dto and struct.

**dto.go**

```
Type Config struct {
    ConfigA             *bool       `json:”config_a,omitempty”`
    ConfigATimestamp    *int64      `json:”config_a_ts,omitempty”`
    ConfigB             *string     `json:”config_b,omitempty”`
    ConfigATimestamp    *int64      `json:”config_b_ts,omitempty”`
}
```

**configmodel.go**

```
type ConfigModel struct {
     ConfigA            *bool       `sql:"config_a" export:"config_a,omitempty"`
     ConfigATimestamp   *int64      `sql:"config_a_ts" export:"config_b,omitempty"`
     ConfigB            *string `   `sql:"config_b" export:"config_c,omitempty"`
     ConfigBTimestamp   *int64      `sql:"config_b_ts" export:"config_b,omitempty"`
}
```

**api.go (See processTimestamp - This is the function I am trying to implement)**

```
func update(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        
    ctx := r.Context()
    config := ctx.Value(key.Name("config")).(model.ConfigModel)
    dto := ctx.Value(key.Name("dto")).(*Config)

    processTimestamp(ctx, dto, "ConfigA"). *****//trying to pass ctx, dto, and config names****

func processTimestamp (ctx context.Context, dto *config, configName string) {
        now := time.Now().Unix()
        timestamp := configName + “Timestamp”
        if dto.(configName) == nil { 
            config.(configName) = nil
            config.(timestamp) = nil
        }
        config.(configName) = dto.(configName)
        config.(timestamp) = &now
```

Comment: Have a look into the `reflect` package. https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.FieldByName

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Why do you pass config through the `context.Context` of the `http.Request`?  
Why do you pass your dto as well in the context?